# Using 'controller as' syntax to pass object values to parent controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

When using the `$scope` controller syntax, it's simple to set a value on a parent controller's object. For example

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController">
    {{myValue.a}}
    <div ng-controller="ChildController">
        {{myValue.a}}
    </div>
</div>
```

```
app.controller('ParentController', function($scope) {
    $scope.myValue = {};
    $scope.myValue.a = 1;
});
app.controller('ChildController', function($scope) {
    $scope.myValue.a = 2;
});
```

The above outputs:

```
2
2
```

Is there a way to achieve the same functionality with the `controller as` syntax without referencing `$scope` in the child controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using a service, or you could do it referencing the scope.

The behavior that you are using, scope inheritance, is often referred to as an unwanted side affect. This is why isolated scopes are used with the `controllerAs` syntax.

In the following example you can see we achieve the same result using sharing the myValue property on the $scope along with the `controllerAs` syntax.

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('ParentController', ParentController)
  .controller('ChildController', ChildController);

ParentController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function ParentController($scope) {
  this.myValue = {};
  this.myValue.a = 1;

  $scope.myValue = this.myValue;
}

ChildController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function ChildController($scope) {
  this.myValue = $scope.myValue;

  this.myValue.a = 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="ParentController as parent">
    parent: {{parent.myValue.a}}
    <div ng-controller="ChildController as child">
      child: {{child.myValue.a}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This can be accomplished without `$scope` using a service:

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('ParentController', ParentController)
  .controller('ChildController', ChildController)
  .service('valueService', ValueService);

ParentController.$inject = ['valueService'];

function ParentController(valueService) {
  this.myValue = {};
  this.myValue.a = 1;

  valueService.setValue(this.myValue);
}

ChildController.$inject = ['valueService'];

function ChildController(valueService) {
  this.myValue = valueService.getValue();

  this.myValue.a = 2;
}

function ValueService() {

  var storedValue;

  this.getValue = function() {
    return storedValue;
  }

  this.setValue = function(value) {
    storedValue = value;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="ParentController as parent">
    parent: {{parent.myValue.a}}
    <div ng-controller="ChildController as child">
      child: {{child.myValue.a}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't like to use `$scope` you may pass outer controller downstream, see [directives communication](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible from within `ChildController`.

Don't think of ControllerAs as a newer style of `$scope`. Each has a different use.

`ControllerAs` does not publish values onto scope (it actually does - via the alias, but the alias should not be assumed to be known to a child Controller since the alias is defined in the View).

I use both where needed and I use the following convention:

```
app.controller("ParentCtrl", function($scope){
   // $scope-inherited view model
   var VM = $scope.VM = ($scope.VM || {});

   // controller-specific view model
   var vm = this;

   VM.valueVisibleToChildControllers = "foo";
   vm.valueVisibleOnlyToTheView = "bar";
});
```

Comment: I read people saying "use the `$scope` syntax or `ControllerAs`, don't mix them", but your method makes a lot of sense.

Comment: At any rate, the answer to your question is that unless you use `$scope` you can't access scope variables from your controller. You _could_ use `ng-init="childProp = p.parentProp"` but that is hacky, so I don't recommend it. (Neither does Angular documentation recommends `ng-init` for this purpose)